# Автообновление картинки IE (not support)

Tags: javascript, браузер, internet-explorer

работает почти во всех браузерах, но в осле не происходит автообновление, кто может подсказать?

```
   <img src="http://myhost/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi" id="picture" height="480px" width="640px">
    <script>
        function reload(){
            var imageObj = new Image();
            imageObj.src='http://myhost/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi';
            document.getElementById('picture').src=imageObj.src;

            window.setTimeout(reload, 1000);
        }
        reload();
    </script>
```

Comment: Так, вроде как, все работает:  http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/jv9us/show/

Comment: хм, в моем скрипте ie получает только первую картинку и автообновление не происходит :(

Comment: @Владлен Макароф, я преобразовал предыдущий комментарий в ответ, чтобы вы могли его принять, если он вас устраивает.  
Если будете менять размер картинки через стили - эффект будет чисто визуальным. Отдавайте картинку нужного размера со стороны сервера.  
К тому же, неуверен, что вы с помощью javascript пофиксите утечку памяти в браузере (если речь об этом)

Comment: Понял. Спасибо за совет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, он кэширует картинку (такая же проблема есть и в firefox).
Поможет выставление верных заголовков на стороне сервера или добавление случайного get-параметра к ссылке на картинку. Например:

http://myhost/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi?v=1

Comment: Какой именно браузер?

Comment: осел 8 (internet explorer)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> var imageObj = new Image();
> imageObj.src='http://myhost/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi';
> document.getElementById('picture').src=imageObj.src;
> ```

```
document.getElementById('picture').src = 'http://myhost/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi?_=' + Date.now();
```